# How to regex match list of patterns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have list of patterns and I need to return that pattern if that is present in the given string else return None.
I tried with the below code using re module , but I am getting only null in "matches" (when I tried to print matches).
Completely new to corepython and regex,kindly help

```
import re
patterns_lst=['10_TEST_Comments','10_TEST_Posts','10_TEST_Likes']

def get_matching pattern(filename):
   for pattern in patterns_lst:
     matches = re.(pattern,filename)
   if matches:
      return matches
   else:
      return None

print(get_matching pattern("6179504_10_TEST_Comments_22-Nov-2021_22-Nov-2021.xlsx"))
```

Comment: This isnt even valid python. Is this a homework excercise where you have been given some code and you are meant to fix the code and make it work?

Comment: I will happy to help you if you provide code that I could run (and is similar enough to this one) ;)

Comment: @ChrisDoyle definitely this not home work code , I have to pull the report of names from a SFTP server and re-name it accordingly with the matching pattern and sent it via DRF response . The files patterns are almost same , here i just replaced the original file names with "sample" and "test"

Comment: @kosciej16 you want it has attachment ?

Comment: @SivaPerumal Your code doesn't run, it has various syntax errors.

Comment: @norie I am not sure  how to use regex thats the issue, i dont how find thet matching pattern in the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your function:

```py
def get_matching_pattern(filename):            ## Function name changed
    for pattern in patterns_lst:
        match = re.search(pattern, filename)   ## Use re.search method

        if match:                              ## Correct the indentation of if condition
            return match                       ## You also don't need an else statement
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(get_matching_pattern("6179504_10_TEST_Comments_22-Nov-2021_22-Nov-2021.xlsx"))
<re.Match object; span=(8, 24), match='10_TEST_Comments'>
```